# Access modules local scope with `this` and pass it to imported module

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to import a module B into module A. I want to give module B access to all of the local scope in module A.

Before webpack I did it like this:

```
 var scope = this;
```

Then I would check for existence of entities like this

```
if (!('blah' in scope)) {
          throw new Error('method of "' + 'blah' + '" not in scope')
}
```

I would also be able to set things in module A from module B by doing `scope.blah = ....`

Is this possible with webpack?

I tried with `DefinePlugin` and `ProvidePlugin`, but I can't seem to give module B access to the scope of module A.

Answer (score 1):

The module may export one default object and many named items.

It is default module export:

```
const MyClass = (props) => (
  <div/>
)

export default MyClass
```

We can import it like this:

```
import MyClass from "../actions"
```

The curly braces allows to export named items, so if we have such exports:

```
const myConst = "The Text"
const myHelper = (num) => 2*num

export default MyClass
export {myHelper, myConst}
```

We can import its like this:

```
import MyClass, {myHelper, myConst} from "../actions"
```

There is not need to add index at path - it is add by default. So write "../actions" enough instead of "../actions/index"

So we can import any exported elements of two modules from each other.

For testing purpose the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) module helps to bypass export limitations.

EDIT (after comment):
I try such code:

```
# scope.js
var data = ['The data']
var value = 'The value'
var scope = this
var fn = function(){ return scope }
console.log(scope)
export { scope, value, fn }

# index.js
import { scope, fn } from './scope'
console.log(scope)
console.log(scope.data)
console.log(fn())
```

The result is:

> ```
> { a: [Getter], b: [Getter] }
> { a: [Getter], b: [Getter] }
> undefined
> { a: [Getter], b: [Getter] }
> ```

Where 'a' is `scope` variable, and 'b' is `fn` function. So seems package is strongly isolated.

Comment: Thanks for the ES6 guide here, however my question is different. I need to give the imported module something to access the scope of the place it was imported into.

Comment: I try some and add to answer. Take it as the base (with no any dependencies else) and try to see generated bundle. May be you found solution please leave answer or feedback.

Comment: your experiment result is same as mine. The scope is strongly isolated. I am trying to tap scopes, that is my question.

Comment: I have suggested to analise code of result generated bundle, may be you found some useful, have you see? Also I suggest to use rewire module in answer, is rewite module helpful for your case?